# Generating sql scripts for SQL Server using SQL Management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is it possible to not have the:

/****Script Date: 10/27/2008 09:05:41 ******/

in the output?

I want to use Diff's so I can see what's changed, having a timestamp makes it difficult!

Answer (score 5):

Tools|Options|Scripting|Include Descriptive Headers -> false

Answer (score 3):

The options "Script Descriptive Headers" - set it to false, should do it.